# How to make SVG:A elements clickable when using D3.js Pan & Zoom behaviour?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, d3.js

I have a graph contains "svg:a" elements with xlink:href values set. I need to zoom and pan around the diagram, but I want the "svg:a" elements to still be clickable.

Once I added in the zoom behaviour, the click event no longer gets to the "svg:a" element. How do I fix this?

Note: right click "open in new tab" still works.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0kwudfhc/5/

Here is the running version: http://jsfiddle.net/0kwudfhc/5/embedded/result/

The relevant part of the source:

```
<style>
   ...
          .overlay {
            fill: none;
            pointer-events: all;
          }
   ...
</style>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
        function render(data){

          var svg = d3.select("#diagram")
            .append("svg:svg")
              .attr("width", data.diagram.width)
              .attr("height", data.diagram.height)
              .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0,"+data.diagram.height+")")
                .append("g")
                  .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.5, 8]).on("zoom", zoom))
                  .on("dblclick.zoom", null)
                  .append("g");

          svg.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "overlay")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", -data.diagram.height)
            .attr("width", data.diagram.width)
            .attr("height", data.diagram.height);

          function zoom() {
            svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ") scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
          }

          ...

          var docs = svg.append("g").attr("id", "docs")
          .data([d3.values(data.documents).sort(function(a,b){return a.order - b.order;})])
          .selectAll(".node")
            .data(function(d){return d;})
            .enter()
              .append("svg:a")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("target", "_top")
                .attr("xlink:href", function(d){return d.url;})
                .append("g")
                  .attr("id", function(d){ return "node_"+d.id;})
                  .attr('transform', function(d) { return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")" })
                  .on('mouseover', function(d) { ... })
                  .on('mouseout', function(d) { ... });       

          ...
        };
```

Comment: Could you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Known bug: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1658

Comment: I don't think that bug is related.. but either way it's been open since 2013. I don't expect that to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did in the end was ..

Turned off the double click zoom.

```
 ...
 .append("g")
   .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.5, 8]).on("zoom", zoom))
   .on("dblclick.zoom", null) // <---- turn off double click zoom
   .append("g");
```

And on adding new nodes, added an "on click" handler

```
      ...
              var hrefs = svg.append("g").attr("id", "docs")
    .data([d3.values(data.documents)])
    .selectAll(".node")
      .data(function(d){return d;})
      .enter()
        .append("svg:a")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .attr("target", "_top")
          .attr("xlink:href", function(d){return d.url;})
          .on('click', clickit, true);  // <<<< added on click method
```

Then pulled the url from the "a" element and told the browser to open it in a new tab/window.

```
    function clickit(){
      window.open(this.href.animVal);
    }
```